# creating and calling functions in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new with jquery and I'm having problems in constructing functions.
I need some help on this one?
I'm not sure I've done the correct thing with this functions?

Please explain what is rong in how I wrote the next functions or tell me how to build the correct syntax 
The function member.panel.init('login') doesn't do the right thing.

```
member = {};
member.panel = function(){
    return{
    init: function(a)
    {   
        $('#log_in .login').click(open_menu(a));
        $('#log_in .register').click(open_menu(a));
    },

    open_menu: function(what)
    {
         if(what!='login' || what!='register') what='login';
         $('#q_login_dialog #menu-'+what+'').addClass("q_dialog_panel_item_active");
         if(what=='login')
         {
            $('.q_dialog_content #dialog-form3').css("display", "none");
            $('.q_dialog_content #dialog-form2').css("padding-bottom", "20px");
            $(".login-box").fadeIn('fast'); 
         }
         if(what=='register')
         {
            $('.q_dialog_content #dialog-form2').css('display', '');
            $('.q_dialog_content #dialog-form3').css("padding-bottom", "20px");
            $(".login-box").fadeIn('fast'); 
         }   
    }
}
}();
$(function () {
   member.panel.init('login');
});
```

Comment: `$('#log_in .login').click(open_menu(a));`
 should be `$('#log_in .login').click(function(){open_menu(a)});`

Comment: Have a look at [`Functions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Functions) and [`Working with Objects`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects).... your problem is **not** jQuery related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this:

```
open_menu(a)
```

...you're calling that function. For a handler, you want to *pass* a function to `click()`. The way you're doing it, it looks like you want to retain the value that is passed to `init`. This would mean that you need to have your `open_menu` function return a function that references that value.

Unfortunately, you don't show a function named `open_menu` that is accessible that way. Your `open_menu` function is the member of an object, so that's how you need to access it.

Your code should look like this:

```
member = {};
member.panel = function () {
    return {
        init: function (a) { // use "this.open_menu" to refer to the function
            $('#log_in .' + a).click(this.open_menu(a));
        },
        open_menu: function (what) {

            // "open_menu" now returns a handler function that references "login"
            return function () {
                if (what != 'login' || what != 'register') what = 'login';
                $('#q_login_dialog #menu-' + what + '').addClass("q_dialog_panel_item_active");
                if (what == 'login') {
                    $('.q_dialog_content #dialog-form3').css("display", "none");
                    $('.q_dialog_content #dialog-form2').css("padding-bottom", "20px");
                    $(".login-box").fadeIn('fast');
                }
                if (what == 'register') {
                    $('.q_dialog_content #dialog-form2').css('display', '');
                    $('.q_dialog_content #dialog-form3').css("padding-bottom", "20px");
                    $(".login-box").fadeIn('fast');
                }
            };
        }
    }
}();
$(function () {
    member.panel.init('login');
    member.panel.init('register');
});
```

Or here's an alternative that is closer to Rob W's comment, but fixes the `open_menu` function reference.

```
member = {};
member.panel = function () {
    return {
        init: function (a) {
            var self = this;
            $('#log_in .' + a).click(function() {
                self.open_menu(a); 
            });
        },

        open_menu: function (what) {
            if (what != 'login' || what != 'register') what = 'login';
            $('#q_login_dialog #menu-' + what + '').addClass("q_dialog_panel_item_active");
            if (what == 'login') {
                $('.q_dialog_content #dialog-form3').css("display", "none");
                $('.q_dialog_content #dialog-form2').css("padding-bottom", "20px");
                $(".login-box").fadeIn('fast');
            }
            if (what == 'register') {
                $('.q_dialog_content #dialog-form2').css('display', '');
                $('.q_dialog_content #dialog-form3').css("padding-bottom", "20px");
                $(".login-box").fadeIn('fast');
            }
        }
    }
}();
$(function () {
    member.panel.init('login');
    member.panel.init('register');
});
```

Comment: @sorin: Yes, the code in your `init` isn't quite right. Instead of binding both at the same time, make it two separate calls to `init`, passing `'login'` then `'register'`. But first remove one of the two jQuery lines in `init`, and change the other to look like this: `$('#log_in .' + a).click(this.open_menu(a));`, or like this if you used the second example: `$('#log_in .' + a).click(function() { self.open_menu(a); });`

Comment: Updated. Now you're concatenating the value of `a` into the jQuery selector, so it will look like `'#log_in .login'` for the first call, and `'#log_in .register'` for the second call.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help.
 I've done what you said and also changed the if condition in menu_open()  to  if (what != 'login' && what != 'register') what = 'login';

Comment: @sorin: Ah yes, I didn't spot that. Glad it's working for you.

Comment: If your still there I have a question!! If I'm using the second example with var self=this why if I drop var selft and use direct  this.open_menu(a) insted of self.open_menu(a)  the function isn't runing correctly

Comment: @sorin: Still here. What's up?

Comment: @sorin: Because `this` in JavaScript is a funny thing. Its value changes based on *how* the function is called. So when you do `member.panel.init()`, you're calling `init` from the `panel` object. This sets `this` as that `panel` object. But when your handler is invoked, `this` will be a reference to the element that received the event. So its value changes based on how the function was called, not where the function is created. Because of this, we retain a reference to the initial value of `this` via the `self` variable. You could also do `member.panel.open_menu(a)`.

Answer (score 0):

Rob W is right

Just for explanation: The first parameter for .click() is supposed to be a function reference. In your code the first parameter is the result of the immediate call(!) to the function open_menu() with parameter a. Only if the result (the return value) of this call were a function reference this would result in a valid .click() parameter.

If you move your code into an anonymous function() like Rob W proposed, it will result in a function reference (to this anonymous function) which will only be executed when the click event is fired.

Comment: Well I have run the code after I made the modification from Rob W  but I still got no result's from the function.

Comment: @sorin: Rob W's comment was almost correct, but not quite. Try the code in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8375699/376743). I provided two variations on the same concept. Either should work for you.